# Schematic point of view of the theorem on independence of characters

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In $\S9.2.3$, Ravi Vakil shows in his notes that $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}\times_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}}\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}$ is the disjoint union of two copies of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}$. He then proceeds to say that if $L/K$ is a finite Galois extension, then $L\otimes_K L=L^G$, which I understand. Now, he says that this is a restatement of the theorem on independence of characters. Why is that?

Comment: Well, in what form do you know the theorem you're asking about? This should be rather straightforward with the right phrasing...

Comment: By Ravi Vakil, which book do you mean, FoAG?

Comment: @LawNgai, yes! It is the Foundations of Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: @KReiser, I know it is this way: we say that a character is a morphism $\chi:G\to L^\times$ of abelian groups. Then any set of distinct characters is linearly independent if $L$. In this theorem, $G$ is not necessarily the Galois group of a finite extension, nor is it necessarily finite. Also, $L^G$ is the ring of all the *functions* $G\to L$ and so it is a lot larger than the group of characters.